# Connect to PASSPORT emulator using RUBY

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, mainframe

I am trying to connect with PASSPORT emulator (mainframe) using Ruby. So far i got nothing.
There are gems like TE3270 etc available for different emulators but nothing for PASSPORT.

I also tried using rautomation but if i use that i won't be able to read mainframe screens.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the supported emulators are

```
EXTRA! X-treme by Attachmate
Quick3270 by DN-Computing
X3270
```

The first two are commercial products and need to be purchased. `X3270` is open source.